# Debug third-party library dll in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, dll, visual-studio-debugging

I have third-party dll with lib files.

```
A.dll, A.lib, Ad.lib.
```

One dll, but two lib files - one for debug other for release. And headers. Is there a way to debug into this dll? I don't have source code and don't have pdb files.

PS: I'm using MS Visual Studio.

Comment: Since there is a debug version of the static lib, `Ad.lib`, I assume there should be a debug  version of the DLL, `Ad.dll`. However, without the PDB, you can't debug. You could disassemble the module, but that's not going to help you very much. I don't think you want to do debugging that way.

Comment: Hi Bruice, any update about this issue? If my answer helps you handle the issue, please do not forget to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). And if not, please feel free to let us know:)

Answer (score 0):

That is obvious. You cannot do that. If you want to debug into the dll, you must have the **PDB** file of it. And there is no other way unless you have the source code in recompile to get **PDB** file.

**Or** you could use decompilation tools to parse the dll and get the source code to realize it. But it might have some risks.